# How to sort SELECT results randomly, but in "groups" (NOT grouped by)

Tags: sqlite, random, sql-order-by

I have an SQLITE database with info about music files - i.e. with album, track columns (and some more, but for simplicity I will leave them out).

```
[table SONGS]
ALBUM     TRACK
A1        1
A1        2
A2        1
A2        2
A3        1
A3        2
A4        1
A4        2
```

I know I can do `SELECT album, track FROM songs ORDER BY random()`, but I will get the albums scrambled like:

```
ALBUM     TRACK
A4        2
A3        2
A2        1
A1        1
A3        1
A1        2
A2        2
A4        1
```

And I want to randomize the order, but keep the albums together, like:

```
ALBUM     TRACK
A3        1
A3        2
A2        1
A2        2
A1        1
A1        2
A4        1
A4        2
```

How can I do that? I tried many things (with an additional table with `SELECT DISTINCT album FROM songs ORDER BY random()`), but none of that worked.

I know I can do that in code (I'm writing in XOJO), but I want to use SQLITE to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is with a temporary table (which you might not want to make temporary if you want to play those songs over a long time).
The INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is automatically filled with autoincrementing values:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AlbumOrder(Album, Sort INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO AlbumOrder(Album)
SELECT DISTINCT Album
FROM Songs
ORDER BY random();

SELECT Album, Track
FROM Songs
JOIN AlbumOrder USING (Album)
ORDER BY Sort, Track;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just need to order by Album before of random :

```
SELECT album, track FROM songs ORDER BY album, random()
```

Comment: I afraid it's not that simple - it sorts by album and then sorts the tracks randomly. So - it's not what I need.

Comment: Because I don't want the albums to be sorted alphabetically - please look at my examples above.

Comment: And, so on what criteria you want the album being sorted ? You need to choose a criteria and put before the order on random ...

Comment: I want to sort albums randomly but in groups - together. We can forget the `tracks` column even. I don't want to break the "A1, A1", "A2, A2" groups.